# What could be the sorting algorithm that leads to this biased sorting behaviour?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

For this problem, we are interested in sorting an array of length up to 7. The entries of the array consists of two components, its index and a sorting key. The sorting key is an integer in the range between 1 and 4 (inclusive).
As an example, an array we start with can look like this:

```
[{'index': 0, 'val': 1}, {'index': 1, 'val': 2}, {'index': 2, 'val': 1}].
```

Any programmer know how to sort an array of this kind, i.e. by calling a built-in sorting algorithm of the programming language or write one on his/her own. This question is not about that.

In this problem, I have *observed* a large set of outputs of the sorting algorithm, and my goal is to figure out *which* sorting algorithm is used.

The outputs I have collected are as follows.

- The fraction of the first element in the sorted array only: [link](https://pastebin.com/KW6hPFfe).
- Array of length 5: [link](https://pastebin.com/g8tkCz6S).
- Array of length 4: [link](https://pastebin.com/W5wQxuQj).

As it can be seen, the sorted array has a very biased distribution when it comes to tie-breakers (entries that have the same value). For example, for array

```
[{'index': 0, 'val': 2}, {'index': 1, 'val': 1}, {'index': 2, 'val': 1}, {'index': 3, 'val': 1}].
```

The chance of index 1 being the second item in the sorted array is only 12.5%, whereas the chance of index 2 being the second item is 50%.

I have tried reproducing the bahaviour of this mysterious sorting algorithm using most of the known [unstable sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) but I have no luck.

One key observation I have is that the probabilities in a lot of the cases are powers of two (or sums of them). So it sounds like the underlying algorithm is a comparison based algorithm to me.
I tried reproducing the behaviour of the algorithm with many known sorting algorithms but nothing fits so far.

The algorithm with the closest behaviour is [QuckSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) with the middle element as the pivot. In QuickSort, for an array of length n, if all of the elements are equal in value, the probability of the pivot appearing as the first element is 2<sup>-(n-1)</sup>. But the chance that the middle element appearing first in the observed samples is 2<sup>-n</sup> instead. So QuickSort cannot be the answer to this.

So my question is: do anyone know what (potentially ill-implemented) sorting algorithm can produce this bebaviour? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe its a variation of Quicksort with a different strategy of choosing the pivot element (e.g. randomly, median of first, middle, last element, etc.)

Comment: Sounds very likely to be some kind of quicksort. There is no single quicksort algorithm, there are many with minor differences.

Comment: Most sorting algorithms are deterministic. Give them exact same input and they produce exact same output. If you have different output for the same input then there is some random action involved. Random action that is artificially added to the algorithm. But in that case any algorithm can produce any output, given the appropriate random sequence.

Comment: @Gandhi (and kaya3) Thank you for your input. I initially think it is a variant of QuickSort too, but there is no way you can produce a 2^-n as the probability of observing any element as the first element because no element is compared to any other element n times in QuickSort to begin with.

Comment: @Dialecticus I do agree with you that randomness is involved in this algorithm (to resolve tie-breakers). This question is about which algorithm and what kind of randomness are used.

Comment: Anything is a sum of powers of two.

Comment: @n.m. By the sum of powers of two, I mean the probability of observing any particular sorted array seems to be a power of two (not a sum). And the probability of observing a particular index at a particular position in the sorted array is a sum of powers of two. This is different from representing a random number as a sum of powers of two.

Comment: Do you have timings, too? _Ie_, what if 10000 elements were given?

Comment: The array only goes up to length 7. And there is no reasonable timing side channel available sadly.

Comment: I still don't quite get the server's response. And you are sorting in reverse? What does "first element in the sorted array only" mean?

Comment: @Neil Yes, sorting is in reverse (bigger value goes first). "First element in the sorted array only" means the following. Suppose that we are trying to sort array [{'index': 0, 'val': 1}, {'index': 1, 'val': 1}, {'index': 2, 'val': 1}]. The sorted array will have the same elements, but in a potentially different order. Here, we look at the first element of the array only and we are interested in its index.

Comment: @Neil To give you an example, when the sorting algorithm sorts the array [{'index': 0, 'val': 2}, {'index': 1, 'val': 1}, {'index': 2, 'val': 1}, {'index': 2, 'val': 1}], the first element in the sorted array will be {'index': 0, 'val': 2} all the times. But the chance for {'index': 1, 'val': 1} to be the second element in the sorted array is only 12.5%, way below 1/3 if elements with equal value are uniformly randomly distributed. QuickSort can produce a similar bias, but as I have argued, QuickSort cannot produce this level of bias no matter how the pivot is chosen.

Comment: Seems like some sort of [shell sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) using pseudo-random gap sequences? How much do you expect the server to be sneaky? A list limit of 7 is kind of limiting.

Comment: @Neil I did try shell sort and comb sort but no luck there. Maybe you have an idea of what gap sequence should be used to produce the behaviour of the observed samples? In terms of the server, I expect the devs to use available libraries (unknown language/platform) instead of inventing their own sorting algorithm. But there is a chance that they have done something dumb somewhere as I have seen time and time again. I wish I could just ask what they have done, but it is not an option.

Comment: I think shell sort is deterministic, it will always give you the same answer with the same gap sequence. Any sequence with 1 at the end will work, and practically, there are only space for 2 maybe 3 numbers in 7. Maybe they pick a random number and then 1. However, this is kind of convoluted. You probably want an unstable random algorithm built-in?

Comment: But tie-breakers are not deterministic? When two elements have the same value, I think the algorithm returns > or < with 50% probability each. That is why the probabilities (for different sorted arrays) we see are powers of two.

Comment: It depends what the goal of the server is? They could make it difficult for you to guess by making that the case, but usually a compare is deterministic? Picking the pivot randomly in quicksort is probably the most standard kind of algorithm, but then Hoare / Lomuto partitioning. I have never heard of shell sort with random gaps.

Comment: But I am looking for an algorithm that produces the observed distribution. If shell sort + deterministic comparison does not give us that, then it is not the algorithm we are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the sorting algorithm is just to rearrange the array based on the number of possible combinations, which is `N!`. The algorithm is as follows:

- Pick a random number between 0 to N! - 1
- Unpack this number into a combination of N elements
- Transform input array using this combination
- If the array is sorted return, else repeat from the first step

Comment: Is this [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)?

Comment: If this is what the algorithm does, shouldn't the sorted arrays be uniformly distributed (provided that it is sorted)? We do not have this uniformity in the observed samples.

Comment: @Divinity_123, uniformity is not guaranteed. Everything is pseudo-random. Random things can happen in random distributions.

Comment: @Neil, huh it has a name. It appears to be exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Pseudorandom generators have high enough entropy to avoid extreme biases like 2^{-n} as far as I know. I think the bias, in this case, is generated by the sorting algorithm itself instead.

Comment: @Divinity_123, not all pseudorandom generators are made equal. Or good. maybe the "random" sequence is not random at all. If you already have the answer to your question then fine, test our guessing skills. If you don't have the answer then any "good enough" guess is good enough.

Comment: No, I don't know the answer to the question either. And I do want to find it out and reproduce it. I do appreciate your answer but just saying that some PRG will generate this distribution doesn't help reproduce the distribution.

Comment: @Divinity_123 in a more practical approach, if you have the executable code you can disassemble it and figure it out from assembly code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the code. The code is executed on a server and I can only collect the output from the client.

Comment: It seems like this is a good guess based on the all-one-value test, which seems to distribute them about evenly. I still can't really understand what the server says.

Comment: This is a bad guess because the output is NOT distributed evenly in the samples I have observed. See the samples with values (2, 1, 1, 1) in the "Array of length 4" for an example.